# Convert dmoz directory to mind map tree

Tags: dmoz, mindmap

www.dmoz.org provides comprehensive web category in RDF file here http://www.dmoz.org/rdf.html

I would like to create a mind map(using tools like free mind for example) or a visual tree using the RDF file from above link.

Is there any easy way for this?